# Android ImageSwitcher example

Tags: android-widget

Can anyone give me a working example of an ImageSwitcher without a Gallery?

Here's my code:

```
         ImageSwitcher mImageSwitcher;
         mImageSwitcher = new ImageSwitcher(this);
         mImageSwitcher.setLayoutParams(new
                ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                           LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        mImageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mImageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));
        mImageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
```

And I do this to display a new picture:

```
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        mImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(d);
```

OK, this causes animation to the new image.  How do I set the previous image in this animation?

There are two images displayed here, "previous" and "next".  I know how to set the "next" image.  I would like to know how to set "previous". I would expect that to be the image currently displayed, but that does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the next image with setImageDrawable method. Of course next image can be your previous image! for example:

```
setImageDrawable(preimage)
```

Comment: There's also the showPrevious() and showNext() methods in the ImageSwitcher class.  My code looks like this:  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);  mViewFlipper.showPrevious();  mViewFlipper.setImageDrawable(d);