# how to fade in 1 image fade out 2nd image?

Tags: android

i found this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html   which fade in fade out same image how do change this code to use two images fade in 1 image fade out 2nd automatically???

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class AndroidAnimTranslateActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button buttonFadeOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fadeout);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

     Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);

    image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
    animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

        }
    });
    final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  
 R.anim.fadeout);
    buttonFadeOut.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
        }});
 }
}


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/hello" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/fadein"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fade In"/>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/fadeout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fade Out"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>    

     </LinearLayout>



         <!-------fadein.xml-->>


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
 <alpha 
    android:fromAlpha="0.1" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:duration="2000" 
    />
     </set>



 <!--------fadeout.xml----->


               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha 
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
    android:toAlpha="0.1" 
    android:duration="2000" 
    />
</set>
```

Comment: You can use ImageSwitcher. [Here][1] you can find an example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987839/android-imageswitcher-example

Comment: Declare final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  
 R.anim.fadeout); before image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

Comment: And I think you should call buttonFadeIn's onClick

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Animationlistener:

```
image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

                }
            });
```

So second animation will be started while first will end

Comment: You can use image2.startAnimation() if there are two different imageviews. Or if you have same imageview, and you want to change its source dynamically, you can add that line before image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut); line. Do let me know if there is any problem

Comment: @LovelyGuy this is the correct answer. If you want to animate both of them at same instance simple call second animation in onAnimationStart methode.

Comment: is not helping me no method found for setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

Comment: The method setAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener) in the type Animation is not applicable for the arguments (new AnimationListener(){})

Comment: @LovelyGuy Is there any other compiler error, which says to override methods of listener?, or which says to import listener?

Comment: see above now i edit myc ode which i compile  see my  original code again plz